# SQL a cumulative distinct count

Tags: sql, group-by, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQL table that lists individual events and I am trying to aggregate to get a group of events as follows.

```
id |Name | Date|
0  |A    |2018-05-08
1  |A    |2018-05-09
2  |B    |2018-05-11
3  |B    |2018-05-12
4  |A    |2018-05-17
5  |A    |2018-05-17
6  |A    |2018-05-18
7  |C    |2018-05-25
8  |C    |2018-05-26
9  |B    |2018-05-27
```

Becomes:

```
Name|Group
|A  |1
|B  |2
|A  |3
|C  |4
|B  |5
```

This I believe is some form of a Count(), then OVER BY, which have always tripped me up. I do not know what I would even count over because there is little grouping these Names together. So far, I have the following:

```
select
    Name
    ,Count(Name)
from table
Group BY
    Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to think of this as a gap-and-islands problem.  I mean, it is, but there is a simpler solution.

In this case, use `lag()` and `row_number()`:

```
select name, row_number() over (order by date, id) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(name) over (order by date, id) as prev_name
      from t
     ) t
where prev_name is null or prev_name <> name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and island problem, where you want to group together "adjacent" rows.

One approach relies on the difference between row numbers to indentify the groups. If `id` is continously increasing by `1`, consider:

```
select 
    name,
    row_number() over(partition by name, id - rn order by min(date)) grp
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by name, id - rn
order by grp
```

Otherwise, we can generate the `id` with `row_number()`:

```
select 
    name,
    row_number() over(partition by name, rn1 - rn2 order by min(date)) grp
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by name, rn1 - rn2
order by grp
```

Comment: That gets me what I would like, but I should have specified. Is there a way to order by date?

Comment: @JackArmstrong: `order by min(date)`.

Comment: order by min(date) instead of grp. Also I included max(date) in the overall select*from, just as max(date).